# Selenium Configuration Failures while running TestNG

Tags: selenium, parameters, testng

In selenium why does the result
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0 comes?
Why is this so. I was trying to run a test.

```
public class NewTest {
WebDriver driver;
@BeforeTest
@Parameters({"browser"})
public void setup(@Optional String browser) throws Exception{
if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")){

  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }
else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path");
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
 }
else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")){
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","path");
 driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}
else{
 throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
}
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
 @Test

public void testParameterWithXML() throws InterruptedException{

     driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");
     WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("uid"));
     userName.sendKeys("guru99");
     WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
     password.sendKeys("guru99");
}}
```

This is my code. I was trying to run this, but getting errors.

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup(null)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at zproject.NewTest.setup(NewTest.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:217)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:144)
at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:634)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Also

Default test 
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0

suite.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">; 
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" > 
  <parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" /> 
  <test name="ChromeTest">
   <classes>
     <class name="zproject.NewTest"></class>
   </classes>
  </test>
  <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
  <test name="FirefoxTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="zproject.NewTest"></class>
    </classes> 
  </test>
  <parameter name="browser" value="IE" /> 
  <test name="IETest"> 
    <classes> 
      <class name="zproject.NewTest"> </class> 
    </classes> 
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Comment: would you please share your testng.xml file, it will help people to understand if there is any issue with xml file.

Comment: You should share some code too.

Comment: @juherr I have attached the code.

Comment: Which line is number 21? Find the `null` value (I bet `browser`).

Comment: @juherr if(browser.equals("Firefox")){

Answer (score 0):

`@Optional` means the value will be null if you don't configure it.

In your case, I think you didn't and then the value of `browser` is `null` and produces an NPE.

As you throw an exception in the case of a bad browser, just remove the `@Optional` and TestNG will fail as expected.

Next, you'll need a `suite.xml`:

```
<suite name="My suite">
  <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
  <test name="Simple example">
    <classes>
      <class name="NewTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Have a look on [the parameter part of the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml) too.

Comment: I initially did not mark the browser as optional. But I got the error- Parameter 'browser' is required by BeforeTest on method setup but has not been marked @Optional or defined

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="2" parallel="tests" >
<parameter name="browser" value="Chrome" />
<test name="ChromeTest">
<classes>
<class name="zproject.NewTest">
</class>
</classes>
</test>
<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox" />
<test name="FirefoxTest">
<classes>
<class name="zproject.NewTest">
</class>
</classes>
</test>
<parameter name="browser" value="IE" />
<test name="IETest">
<classes>
<class name="zproject.NewTest">
</class>
</classes>
</test>
</suite

Comment: It is supposed to work without `@Optional` and with your suite.

Comment: Try with TestNG 6.10 and only one `<test>` block. Still the same problem?

Comment: Sorry, I've no more idea. Everything looks good in your project from my point of view.